# Haskell regular expressions

Tags: regex, haskell

Im new to learning Haskell and have been using the book "Haskell-The Craft of Functional Programming 3rd edition" and am stuck on Chapter 12 regarding regular expressions, problem 12.16 in particular:

implement the following functions:
   option,plus:: RegExp->RegExp
-where option e matches 0 or 1 occurence of e and plus e matches 1 or more occurence of e.

Im not sure where to evenbegin so any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Check [this resource](https://github.com/c089/haskell-craft3e/blob/master/Chapter12.hs#L52)

Comment: I don't know that this will help with the particular exercise, but [`regex-applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) offers a particularly pleasant API for dealing with regular languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `star` function, `plus` function should be like this:

```
plus :: RegExp -> RegExp
plus e = e <*> star e
```

Where `a <*> b` means "a followed by b", and `star` matches 0 or multiple occurences.

Try to use `epsilon` and `(|||)` for `option` function.